# Print the value of a boolean in Log

Tags: android

Is it possible for me to print the Boolean value returned from a method in a Log message?
I am able to print String values, but I am not sure how to print Boolean values in Log message.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Yes.

```
Log.v("", "" + booleanValue);
```

or

```
Log.v("", Boolean.toString(booleanValue));
```

Comment: Also to note, if you want to Log integers: Log.v("", Integer.toString(intValue));

Comment: If anyone interested, here's the [**smali** equivalent](https://i.imgur.com/Wi9Z2Iq.jpg).

Answer (score 3):

I would do it like this:

```
Log.d("SomeTag" , booleanValue?"true":"false");
```

Comment: There is no need to use conditional operator if we can simply log boolean value as he Pepi suggest .