# Trying to change colors with SharedPreferences but it is not getting in the right way

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to change colors of some text and `MainActivity` from a menu.
I have two menus, white color and black color, if I click white will return the color of background white, buttons black, text black. When I click black will return the color of background grey, buttons white, text, white.
I am trying this to save with `SharedPreferences` but it is not working always it takes the grey color.
If I do this without `SharedPreferences` and click on the `PopUpMenu` it changes the color, but with `SharedPreferences` it is not working something I am writing false.

This is my code in `MainActivity.class`.

```
private boolean switchOnOff;
public static final String Change_Color = "Change_Color";


switchOnOff = getChangeColor();
    if (switchOnOff) {
        setColorGreyImageButton();
    } else {
        setColorWhiteImageButton();

    }

public void setColorGreyImageButton() {
    settings.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#757575"));
    voiceSearch.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#757575"));
    share.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#757575"));
    search.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#757575"));
    mainView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

}


public void setColorWhiteImageButton() {
    settings.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    voiceSearch.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    share.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    search.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    mainView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff212121"));
}

public void saveColor(boolean changeColor) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Color", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(getPackageName() + ".change_color", changeColor);
    editor.apply();

}


  private boolean getChangeColor() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Color", MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(getPackageName() + ".change_color", false);
    }
```

This is the `PopUpMenu` in `MainActivity.class`

```
mPopupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, settings);
        MenuInflater menuInflater = mPopupMenu.getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_settings, mPopupMenu.getMenu());
        settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mPopupMenu.show();
                mPopupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                        int id = item.getItemId();
                        if(id == R.id.menu_back_white) {
                            saveColor(true);
                        } else if (id == R.id.menu_back_black) {
                            saveColor(false);
                        }
       return false;
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: Have you checked that the boolean value is actually saved in shared preferences? And what value is returned? The Apply is asynchronous, so if you are trying to change the color scheme quickly, it might not be enough time to save the flag.

Comment: No I didn't check because I am trying to Log but I cannot create a Log for boolean

Comment: @Spritzig- you [can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369790/print-the-value-of-a-boolean-in-log) create a log that will log out the boolean value.

Comment: It is saving when I exit the app and open again the changes are there but it doestn change the theme when I click do you know how to update quickly ?

Comment: It is coming the error
`setColorFilter
(android.graphics.ColorFilter)
in Drawable cannot be applied
to
(int)`

Comment: Instead of `voiceSearch.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#757575"));` try `voiceSearch.getDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#757575"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);`

Comment: It is doing the same after app is open make changes.

Comment: @forpas I have done something like this but I don't wan't to reload the Activity just only refresh and this code it is reloading.

`Intent intent = getIntent();
        overridePendingTransition( 0, 0);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        finish();
        startActivity(getIntent());
        overridePendingTransition( 0, 0);`

Comment: @Spritzig Of course you don't want to reload the activity. The truth is I have not much experience with drawables so I cannot help you with that. I found these links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44984488/setcolorfilter-is-not-working-sometimes-on-android-drawable and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954042/setcolorfilter-not-working. Maybe these can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
if(id == R.id.menu_back_white) {
   saveColor(false); //I changed true to false 
} else if (id == R.id.menu_back_black) {
   saveColor(true); //I changed false to true
}
```

because when "getChangeColor()" is false you set it to white color:

```
switchOnOff = getChangeColor();
    if (switchOnOff) {
        setColorGreyImageButton();
    } else {
        setColorWhiteImageButton();

    }
```

Comment: I have changed this but it doesn't update the view automatically I need to exit the app and then when I open changes the colors, do you know how to make it to change quickly the view

Comment: Do you call it on OnCreate?

Comment: Before setContentView or after ?

Comment: After setContentView